# error in connecting to SMTP using javamail

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

this is the code that I use to send an email

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Mail extends Authenticator {
    private String _user;
    private String _pass;

    private String[] _to;
    private String _from;

    private String _port;
    private String _sport;

    private String _host;


    private String _subject;
    private String _body;

    private boolean _auth;

    private boolean _debuggable;

    private Multipart _multipart;

    public String[] get_to() {
        return _to;
    }

    public void set_to(String[] _to) {
        this._to = _to;
    }

    public String get_from() {
        return _from;
    }

    public void set_from(String _from) {
        this._from = _from;
    }



    public String get_subject() {
        return _subject;
    }

    public void set_subject(String _subject) {
        this._subject = _subject;
    }


    public Mail() {                 
        _host = "mail.messagingengine.com";    
    _port = "587";  
        _sport = "587"; 
        _user = ""; // username
        _pass = ""; // password
        _from = ""; // email sent from
        _subject = ""; // email subject
        _body = ""; // email body

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
        // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
    }

    public Mail(String user, String pass) {
        this();

        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
    }

    public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
                && !_body.equals("")) {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            msg.setSubject(_subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // setup message body
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(_multipart);


            Transport.send(msg);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.messagingengine.com", _host);
        // mail.messagingengine.com

        if (_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if (_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);


        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
    }

    // the getters and setters
    public String getBody() {
        return _body;
    }

    public void setBody(String _body) {
        this._body = _body;
    }

    // more of the getters and setters …..
}
```

this error apper after command  transport.send(msg);

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.messagingengine.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x1f81518: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:683 0x4025bc93:0x00000000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code works for me

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  public String[] get_to() {
    return _to;
}

public void set_to(String[] _to) {
    this._to = _to;
}

public String get_from() {
    return _from;
}

public void set_from(String _from) {
    this._from = _from;
}

public String get_subject() {
    return _subject;
}

public void set_subject(String _subject) {
    this._subject = _subject;
}

private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public Mail() { 
    _host = "mail.messagingengine.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  } 

  // more of the getters and setters ….. 
}
```

I think the error was in

```
_port = "465"; // default smtp port 
 _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port
```

and this line

```
 props.put("mail.messagingengine.com", _host);
```

see [this](https://www.fastmail.fm/help/remote_email_access_server_names_and_ports.html)